# How to export Multidimensional Arrays in Matlab to MultiIndex Dataframe in Python?

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose I have a multidimensional element in Matlab say

```
M=rand(5,4,3)
```

where the 5 rows stand for say last names of customers and the 4 columns stand for their {age, weight, activities, happiness level}, while the other 3 multi-matrix stands for years {1999,2003,2009}.

I am trying to convert this into a multi-index data frame in Pandas. Can please someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no easy way of doing it,

I will post my solution for later reference. However, if there is anyone who is happy to add an answer that would be much appreciated. However, I do things long way if I did not find easy solutions online. The question I had posted no one answered it before.

In Matlab, I have saved created for each of the dimensions `(:,:,i)`, `i=1,2,3` an excel file as follow:

```
for i=1:3
    xlswrite([num2str(i) '.xlsx'],M(:,:,i))
end
```

Therefore, I have three excel files saved as 1.xlsx, and so on.

Now, I access the same directory in python and I wrote the following code

```
import pandas as pd

# Import the excel file and call it xls_file
df = pd.read_excel('You_working_directory/1.xlsx', header=None)

# Creating Multi indexing for both columns and rows
col_name=['age', 'weight', 'activities', 'happiness level']
row_name=['Rami Chehab','Aya Ghalayini','Bassel Dajani','Mohammad Saab','Huthaifa Abou Hammad']
arrays1 = [['Paid Individuals']*5,row_name]
arrays2 = [['1999']*4,col_name]
rows1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays1, names=['Category', 'Names'])
col1= pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays2, names=['Year', 'Activity']) 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=col1,index= rows1)

# Creating the multi-dimenstional variable which is year in our case
Year=['2003','2009']
for ii in range(0,2):
    df = pd.read_excel("You_working_directory" + str(ii+2)+'.xlsx', header=None)
    arrays2 = [[Year[ii]]*4,col_name]
    col2= pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays2, names=['Year', 'Activity']) 
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=col2,index= rows1)
    # Merge data from the row index
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)
```

The outcome was as I wanted in the question